# Low Quality Posts you Have Already Flagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

I just discovered that it is possible to get a post in the Low Quality Posts review queue that you have already flagged for closing, making reviewing that item impossible. Obviously, I don't want to 'Looks Good' something that I know should be closed, but at the same time I cannot 'Recommend Close' something I have already flagged leaving the only option being to skip the post.

Can the queue be changed so that it does not show posts which you have already flagged?

Comment: Existing logic prevents you from seeing a post you've *voted* to close, but ignores flags (mostly). I guess I can't think of a good reason to have you reviewing a post you've already flagged though, regardless of the type of flag.

Comment: I noticed this a while back as well. Rare but annoying.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging AFAIU. Flagging is actually calling for attention and action. While casting a close vote is that actual action. Right?

Comment: @Mansfield Can easily be found on beta sites.

Comment: @Shog9 any chance to bump this bug internally, two years later? Not critical bug, but it keeps bugging people.

Comment: Could you at least make the *"You flagged this question for closure"* more apparent? At first I thought it was a browser bug that I got the selection of deletion reasons without visible checkboxes.

Comment: So any chance this will get fixed / changed?

Comment: @Shog9 Five years later, any chance of fixing this?

Comment: If / when someone has time, it'll get fixed, @GaurangTandon. No idea if / when that'll be.

Comment: Re: "No idea if / when that'll be" — almost one year later; about 5.5 years after the issue had been raised. :-) I'm actually surprised it _did_ get solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build. I updated the filter for the Low Quality review queue to exclude items flagged by the reviewer. This filter was also updated on some other queues that were missing it.