# Duplicate Review Item

Tags: bug, review, flags, review-audits

I've been doing a lot of reviewing lately. I came across an item that seemed familiar.
[Cross Forest Authentication - RDP - Have to Manually Specify Domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/510700/cross-forest-authentication-rdp-have-to-manually-specify-domain)

I had flagged the question previously and was asked to review it again. I **Flagged** the "answer" and it said that I had already flagged that item, so I chose **No Action Needed**. Which I got a **STOP! Look and Listen** message.

Is this by design?

[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did flag it again, that is what the problem was. When I flagged it again, I got a message saying that I had already flagged that post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You'll have to take my word for it as I don't have a screen shot for the message I got. I *did* flag it. I got a message saying I had already flagged the post. If you look at my flagged posts, you can see it was flagged "very low quality – Nixphoe Sep 22 at 18:38   helpful." I suppose I could have down voted it rather than choosing to No Action Needed, I'll take that as my answer.

Comment: The system's probably borked, but you should have pressed skip in that case.

Comment: OK, sorry, I was wrong. This looks like an edge case, where a post you already flagged is given as audit. There is a [pending feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193128/low-quality-posts-you-have-already-flagged) asking to not show posts you flagged in review, and anyway in those cases - just Skip.