# Reviewing already flagged post

Tags: bug, review, flags

Note: I'm pretty new to reviewing. I couldn't find any posts about this yet, but that may just be my ignorance.

I just got a review, but I'd already flagged the question as duplicate before.

It doesn't really make sense - I'd basically already reviewed it outside the queue. I think the review queue should either auto-"I'm Done" cases like this, or just omit them.

In case it matters, the duplicate flag is still pending.

It happened on Code Review, but I think it belongs on the global meta instead, since it's not got anything to do with that site in particular.

Comment: Did you open another window to review?

Comment: Vaguely similar:  Does [this describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193128/low-quality-posts-you-have-already-flagged#comment604404_193128), but for (probably) a different reason; plus *that's* marked completed (for the other problem)?

Comment: I'd consider it related, but not a duplicate. As for the other window, it was probably another tab, but I'd close the one where I flagged before I opened the one where I reviewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refresh the review page, it *will* show that you have taken an action on the post, and enable the 'I'm Done' button. Which is good; there's no need for the post to be reviewed in this queue anymore, since you've already passed it on to the Close Votes review queue.

I've seen that in some cases, you won't see the First Posts (or Late Answers) review item in the queue if you have already flagged/voted/commented on the post, but sometimes you do still get it. It's a little hard to predict.

Comment: Obviously can't check it without running into it, but sounds like what I wanted to know.